# Git - confusion about merge, rebase and fast-forward

Tags: git

Suppose now I am on `master` branch and the current commit is `c0`. Now I do a `git branch fb` and make 2 more commits `mc1` and `mc2` on `master` branch. After that I do `git checkout fb` and make a commit `fc1` and do `git rebase master`. Now `fc1` should be on top of `mc1` and `mc2`. At last I do `git checkout master` and `git rebase fb` and git fast forwards. I am confused about this fast forward, although I know it's a wise decision that git made. However, according to the definition of rebase, git should see `c0` as the common ancestor of the two branches, so it should apply `mc1` and `mc2` again on top of `fb` - although I know that would be a stupid move but why doesn't it do so?

Besides, in the last step, would `git rebase fb` and `git merge fb` be different since both would just do a fast-forward? If I do a `git merge fb` here, would the new commit also have two parents even though one parent is the ancestor of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the rebase:

[image: Before the rebase]

After `git rebase master`:

[image: After <code>git rebase master</code>]

Therefore `mc2` is the common ancestor and not `c0`. And because `master` does not contain any commits after `mc2` it can be fast forwarded.

---

You can force `git merge` to not do fast forwards using the `--no-ff` option. It will look like this then:

[image: After <code>git merge --no-ff fb</code>]

Comment: @Xufeng Which one exactly?

Comment: Would merge and rebase be different in that situation and which is preferred?

Comment: @Xufeng No they would not. But merges should always be preferred for merges (and obviously for pushed branches). I even recommend always using `--no-ff`, but that is a personal preference.